# Grep file and export vars in loop

Tags: perl, bash, awk, grep

Want to grep file and export the row like separated vars and the last two to be in one var.
After that to create loop and export the vars in html tags.

File view:

```
1.1.1.1 host red  70%     /
1.1.1.1 host green        0%      /dev/shm
1.1.1.1 host green        63%     /staging/om_campaign_files
1.1.1.1 host red  71%     /mnt/OBCDir
```

Expected view after export the vars:

```
<tr><td>1.1.1.1<td/><td>host<td/><td color=red>/mnt/OBCDir<td/></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` just insert each field as needed:

```
awk '{print "<tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$2"</td><td color="$3">"$5"</td></tr>"}' file
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=red>/</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=green>/dev/shm</td></tr>
...
```

Note: also fixed some of the closing tags i.e. `<td/>` to `</td>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something usable in a program, rather than a one-liner at the command prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($ip, $hostname, $color, undef, $mount) = split ' ', $line;
  say "<tr><td>$ip</td><td>$hostname</td><td color=$color>$mount</td></tr>";
}

__DATA__
1.1.1.1 host red  70%     /
1.1.1.1 host green        0%      /dev/shm
1.1.1.1 host green        63%     /staging/om_campaign_files
1.1.1.1 host red  71%     /mnt/OBCDir
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=red>/</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=green>/dev/shm</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=green>/staging/om_campaign_files</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.1.1.1</td><td>host</td><td color=red>/mnt/OBCDir</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -anE 'say "<tr><td>$F[0]<td/><td>$F[1]<td/><td color=$F[2]>$F[4]<td/></tr>"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` solution. I assume the output is generated by some external utility. This external utility is simulated by `cat infile` (see `coproc`). There is no extra fork except calling the external utility.

```
coproc cat infile
while read -u ${COPROC[0]} i j k l m; do
  echo "<tr><td>$i<td/><td>$j<td/><td color=$k>$m</td></tr>"
done
```

This program start a proc in the background. Its `stdout` is redirected to the file handle stored in ${COPROC[0]}. This handle read in the while-loop.

Or without `coproc` (mind the space between `<` and `<(`!):

```
while read i j k l m; do
  echo "<tr><td>$i<td/><td>$j<td/><td color=$k>$m</td></tr>"
done < <(cat infile)
```

If the input is in a file then it can be used like

```
while read i j k l m; do
  echo "<tr><td>$i<td/><td>$j<td/><td color=$k>$m</td></tr>"
done <infile
```